# What makes an on-change functions before clicking?

Tags: odoo-8

Please, i work with on_change and get_inputs.

Here is my code:

***PYTHON:***

```
 def get_inputs(self, cr, uid,ids, convention_id, company_id, context=None):
 ret = []
 if convention_id == False:
 My_error_Msg = 'Please, select your CONVENTION'
 raise osv.except_osv(_("Error!"), _(My_error_Msg))
 return False
 else:
    obj = self.pool.get('seetek.convention.categorie.line')
    obj_ids = obj.search(cr, uid, [('convention_id', '=', convention_id)])
    res = obj.read(cr, uid, obj_ids, ['nom','nature','id'], context)
    for r in res :
        inputs = {  
                  'company_convention_categorie_id': r['id'],
                  'company_id': company_id,
                  'nom': r['nom'],
                  'nature': r['nature'],
                  'actif': True,
                   }
      ret.append(inputs)
 return ret
 def on_change_convention_id(self, cr, uid, ids, convention_id, company_id, context=None):
 res = {'value':{line_ids': self.get_inputs(cr, uid, ids, convention_id, company_id, context=context),
 }
 }
 return res
```

***XML:***

```
  <field name="convention_ids" on_change="on_change_convention_id(convention_ids,company_ids)" attrs="{'invisible': [('company_ids','=',False)]}"/>
```

My question is that, before i click on the convention_ids field the get_inputs functions and give me all the values??

Please, who can help?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem.
In fact the get_inputs function was perfect and there was no problem.
The issue that makes the problem coming is in the on_change.
Si i have changed it to the code bellow and it works perfectly:

```
  def on_change_conventions_id(self, cr, uid, ids, convention_id, company_id, context=None):
    if company_id == False:
    My_error_Msg =  'Please, select your COMPANY'
    raise osv.except_osv(_("Error!"), _(My_error_Msg))
else:
    print company_id
    print convention_id
        res = {'value':{'seetek_line_ids': self.get_inputs(cr, uid, ids, convention_id, company_id, context=context),
                  }
            }
        return res
```

Thanks a lot & Regards :)